# How to get a background to apply to only one div in a flex layout in tailwind css

Tags: tailwind-css

I have the following HTML in my page with tailwind css.
So I'm trying to have an image and some text side by side. The whole div has a background set. The background is also applying a shadow to the image which I don't want. How do I achieve it?
Is my approach wrong? Can you suggest an alternative approach, if I'm doing it wrong. Thanks!

```
<div class="container relative min-w-full h-dvh" >
<!--- some other code here -->
  <div class="bg-green-50 opacity-50 absolute mt-[200vh] md:mt-[100vh] px-10 py-2 pt-20 md:pt-32 pb-20 w-full">
    <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row md:ml-52 md:mr-52">
        <div class=" md:basis-1/2 pt-4 z-10">
        <img class="max-w-64 max-h-64 mx-auto md:basis-1/2 pt-4" src="images/img.jpeg"></div>
        <p class="text-center font-serif text-xl md:px-32 pt-4">
            <span class="text-xl font-bold">Meet your coach</span>  <br> <br>
          <span class="text-lg italic">I'm Andy, your basketball coach</span></p>  
    </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: close the img tag